# How to prevent simple keras autoencoder from over compressing data?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to use the `keras` frontend with `tensorflow` backend for a simple `autoencoder` as a multidimensional scaling technique to plot multidimensional data into 2 dimensions.  Many times when I run it (not sure how to set random seed for `keras` btw) one of the dimensions is collapsed to yield a 1 dimensional embedding (the plot should help explain).  Why is this happening? **How can I make sure the dimensions are preserved and utilized by the autoencoder?** I realize this is the most simple and basic form of an autoencoder that I have implemented but I would like to build on this to make better autoencoders for this task.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import model_selection
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
X = load_iris().data
Y = pd.get_dummies(load_iris().target).as_matrix()
X_tr, X_te, Y_tr, Y_te = model_selection.train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.3, stratify=Y.argmax(axis=1))
dims = X_tr.shape[1]
n_classes = Y_tr.shape[1]

# Autoencoder
encoding_dim = 2  

# this is our input placeholder
input_data = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,))

# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(encoding_dim, 
                                activation='relu', 
                               )(input_data)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_data, decoded)

# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = tf.keras.models.Model(input_data, encoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
network_training = autoencoder.fit(X_tr, X_tr,
                                    epochs=100,
                                    batch_size=5,
                                    shuffle=True,
                                    verbose=False,
                                    validation_data=(X_te, X_te))

# Plot data
embeddings = encoder.predict(X_te)
plt.scatter(embeddings[:,0], embeddings[:,1], c=Y_te.argmax(axis=1), edgecolor="black", linewidth=1)
```

#### Run algorithm once

[image]

#### Run algorithm again

[image]

Comment: Hello Orka, I think that the situation here is due to the fact that deep learning (specifically the back-propagation algorithm) is a stochastic procedure. This means that every time you train it you are going to get different results. In this case I think that in some runs your chances were that it embedded the data successfully, where in others your model fails to reach an optimum performance. This is a common thing in Deep Learning, and an open problem for computer sciences (spec. optimization algorithms). Usually you have to try several runs before you reach a model that satisfies you.

Comment: What do your plots represent exactly? Plus, the axes units (?) are not the same between the two plots (they seem to be flipped?)

Comment: Yea, it makes sense why they would look completely different since it's a stochastic procedure but I was wondering if there some type of parameter or transformation I could apply that could avoid getting stuck in a local minimum to fit the data to only one neuron in the bottle neck layer.   The axis show the first and second dimensions of the embedding in the bottleneck layer for my autoencoder.

Comment: Ok you have the code to train the complete auto enconder model. Can you show the rest of the code?  using the encoder (half of that model),  adding layers  (dense and softmax) post training and do the classification using the compressed encoded info ?

Comment: By the way ... the train_test_split data shuffle the data(internally) also in the train you have shuffle again ... may that is the main cause for diferrent results ... also adding more layers in encoder/decoding and using relu probably help to be more resilient(?).  I think there are type of layers specific for autoencoders (?) not sure ... you are doing a autoencoder with dense layers ... also try to use a diferent error function ... instead of binary cross entropy

Comment: Can you try to put `seed`? example: `RANDOM_SEED = 7` `np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)` `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(RANDOM_SEED)`

Comment: I guess , there is a bug in your loss function. Shouldn't that be 'mean_squared_error'?  Please see my version of auto encoder  in keras on iris data set here: https://www.kaggle.com/chandrak/autoencoder-with-iris